# JIRA OAuth Issues

Tags: c#, api, authentication, jira

there
I want to use JIRA API to access data from my company's JIRA instance. The steps of login process on internet browser are:

1. Type https://mycompanyname.atlassian.net
2. Direct to login page.
3. Type my company email address
4. It re-directly to Microsoft authentication page, click "Continue".
5. Type password of my Azure AD domain account.
6. Select a method to verify my identify (I select way of verifying code sent to my bind mobile)
7. Bingo!

My questions are:

1.How can I finish above steps by C# code?

2.Does my application need the mobile text code verification for every instance?

FYI:
I want to put my application on Azure function as a timer trigger to run some data from JIRA. However, I get stuck at first step-authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you have already solved your issue. But from an azure function there is a few steps you will need to take.

1. In Azure use Managed Identity, you will need this for function to get some details you will save into Keyvault
2. Have a Keyvault ready cause you gonna need it to get some secrets out of it
3. Create your Function app and install `Atlassian.SDK` - can see documentation [here](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/master/)
4. In the dependency injection of your function call

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager())
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            container.Register(p => Options.Create(config.Get<ConfigDetailsModel>()))
                .SingleInstance();
```

5. In your Jira service use the following to signin

```
public JiraService(IOptions<ConfigDetailsModel> config)
        {
            _config = config.Value;            
        }

var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(_config.JiraUri, _config.JiraUserName, _config.JiraApiKey);

var result = await jira.Projects.GetProjectsAsync();
```

6. Go to `https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens` and create an API key for your password as plaintext passwords are not supported anymore by Jira.
7. Save your username, password and url into keyvault, make password expire at some point.

This should work. Unfortunately the OAUTH way, more secure than the basic way is not really geared towards system-to-system way, well not that I could find, as it requires a user input to allow verification code. If you do not mind moving the flow out of function and into a user flow with OAuth then best article I found is [here](https://erazerbrecht.wordpress.com/2020/12/20/jira-oauth-net/), but you need to copy additional things from his [github](https://github.com/ErazerBrecht/jira_oauth/tree/master/JiraOauth) to get it to work. I got this flow working in Blazor, and tried to get it to work in my Servicebus triggered function.

The only way I could get the Jira stuff to work in function for service-to-service was to use basic Auth either via the `Atlassian.SDK` or Httpclient

**Note** SDK makes life somewhat easier than writing own http client stuff

```cs
            var client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(_config.JiraUri)
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            var authenticationString = $"{_config.JiraUSerName}:{_config.JiraApiKey}";
            var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationString);

            var project = await client.GetAsync($"rest/agile/1.0/epic/{projectId}");
            var content = await project .Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**UPDATE**

When you create an API key in Jira for use in code, know that the API key in JIRA is tied to the person who created it.

1. It should be an Admin account
2. Create a global break glass account to manage this, you do not want an apikey tied to a user that might leave in a few months
3. This break glass account should belong to your `DevOps` team and no one else who can exploit this api key